# How do I set up my Web Server, to return a JSON String query?

Tags: json, database, http, webserver

In its most basic form, what I want to do is access data on my web server, from an Android App I'm developing (to be clear, different apps accesses the same data set).
To be more specific, I would like to set up my Web Server so that it returns a JSON String, in response to an HTTP GET request sent from the app. (That's not a requirement by any means, it just seems like how most APIs work).
So far, it seems I need a Web Framework with an MVC, like Ruby on Rails that uses a controller that can decide what to do with an HTTP GET request.
What I don't quite understand yet (not that I understand what I've said so far), is this:

- How the data is stored (I know I can use a database, but I'd like to know the best/other options)
- How to get query parameters from the URI
- How to retrieve the data
- How to organize the data into a JSON object/string
- How to send the JSON string in response to the GET request

Obviously, I'm not a web development expert. I'm trying to learn, but I don't have the experience yet to even know what to search for. So I appreciate any help and resources you may have.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is far to broad and too fuzzy. It basically asks: tell me everything I need to know about programming the server side. It is not possible to answer to such a question. I suggest you take a look at a few "getting started" tutorials about some server side scripting languages. The examples will answer your questions.

Comment: I wasn't expecting to learn all of that here, I was just hoping to get linked to some resources. Like I said, I'm not even sure what to search for. If you know some good "getting started" pages, I would love to see them.

Comment: Oh, you defined pretty precise aspects what you are looking for, that is not the issue you deal with. You "just" have to decide for a platform (ruby, php, ...) and then use google. We all started that way. Just do it, you will see, it is easier than it sounds.

Comment: All of the resources I've found have been on small parts of what I want. I'm not sure how to put it all together, which is what I was hoping to find here.

Comment: Then you should post a specific question. Pointing out what your current understanding is, add your code and ask about the specific issue that is puzzling you. You will not find someone here willing to take you by the hand, sorry.

Comment: Is there not a term or software that summarizes the structure I've described? It seems like something that's common enough to have such a thing. Also, the reason I was so broad was because I didn't want to assume that the information I gathered was all correct. I was just hoping to get some resources or terminology that would help me guide my search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117283/discussion-between-arkascha-and-tylerc112).